# PS4 DLC code and region

Tags: ps4, psn, region-lock, rocket-league

I'm looking to buy the Rocket League Collector's Edition- I already have the base game, I just want the DLC codes which come with the Collector's Edition.

My PSN account is Brazilian but I'm currently living in Japan, so I wanted to buy the game at any store here or on Amazon US... My question is: If I buy the game, will I be able to use the DLC codes in my PSN? Will it cause a region lock since my account is Brazilian but the physical version would be American or Japanese? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PS4-Support/PS4-is-region-locked/m-p/21205401),

> As far as games are concerned, any game bought from any country will play on any console.
>
> As far as accounts are concerned, any game bought from any country will play on any account registered to any country.
>
> Psn codes are locked to the country they are bought from, and MUST match the country of the psn account.
>
> DLC is region locked, and must match the region of the psn account, AND the region the game was bought from.