# Transferring saves between different-region versions on same account

Tags: ps4, region-lock

I purchased Horizon: Zero Dawn abroad and played it on my Brazilian console and account. I really enjoyed it, so I purchased its Frozen Wilds DLC, only to discover that [DLC is region-locked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/285484/218575). So Brazilian DLC with non-Brazilian disk means I just threw money away.

Now, one solution would be to buy a Brazilian disk (or download the main game via the PS Store). I don't know if I'm willing to pay full-game price for some DLC, but let's assume I am.

However, that leads me to my question: would I be able to transfer my save from the international version to the Brazilian one? I know saves can't be transferred between accounts, but this would all be on the same account on the same console, just between different "versions" of the same game.

I just don't want to invest more money on this game only to discover that the DLC now works, but I have to start from scratch because I can't transfer my save between "disks".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no official way to accomplish this. I can't speak for DIY solutions, but I doubt there's much in that way. The very simple reason is that a game from a different region has a different internal code.

The only solution in your situation, keeping your savefile, is to create an additional PSN account in the region that your base game is in (for example, USA). Then, purchase the DLC in the appropriate PSN store. Afterwards, you can safely swap back to your original PSN account. The DLC should be available for play.

If you don't mind losing your savefile, your options are indeed as you stated - buy a new disc, or buy it digitally.

Comment: Wait, so if I create an account in the disk's region, log into it on my console (in Brazil), and buy the DLC again with that account, the DLC will install? And it will be available for my Brazilian account as well, such that I don't lose my save?

Comment: Yes, that should work from what I gather on the internet. I have not tried it myself, though.

Comment: Here's a post from the PSN messageboards that might help: https://community.playstation.com/content/pdc/us/en_US/pdc-communities/support/games-services.topic.html/how_to_get_dlc_from-hjN2.html

Comment: Ok, I'm going to ponder whether I'm willing to buy the DLC again (damn sunk cost bias!) before accepting this answer. If I do, I'll be the guinea pig to confirm this works (though that PSN link looks quite promising!). If I don't, I'll just accept it in a few days.

Comment: I hope it will work out! If I might add - the DLC was very good :)